# How to convert this into dtd attribute?

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<review rating="5"reviewer="Peterson Johnston">
```

Should the code be something like this?

```
<!ATTLIST review then i don't really know how the syntax goes.
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
<!ATTLIST review rating   NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST review reviewer CDATA   #REQUIRED>
```

or

```
<!ATTLIST review rating   NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
                 reviewer CDATA   #REQUIRED>
```

The syntax (for one attribute) is:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-usage>
```

Numbers are usually `NTOKEN` (no spaces or special characters allowed), and strings `CDATA`. You can also have an enumeration of NMTOKENS `(option1 | option2)`. The attribute types can also be `#IMPLIED` (optional), `#FIXED "value"`, a default value `"value"` .